# I can't post to Twitter using cURL and PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I am unable to tweet continuously in twitter - every three tweets I get:

> Error posting to Twitter. Retry

How do I fix this?

My code is as follows:

```
$host = "http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xmlstatus=".urlencode(stripslashes(urldecode($message)));
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// Look at the returned header
$resultArray = curl_getinfo($ch);
//print_r($resultArray);
if($resultArray['http_code'] == "200"){
     $twitter_status='Your message has been Tweeted';
     update_tweet_extra($result_id,"1");
} else {
 $twitter_status="Error posting to Twitter. Retry";
 // update_tweet_extra($result_id,"0");
}
echo  $twitter_status;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use API with basic authentication since 31 august 2010. You can use a small spider function with curl that login in, fetch your home, and tweet. I made it:
http://www.barattalo.it/2010/09/09/how-to-change-twitter-status-with-php-and-curl-without-oauth/
If you don't want to use oAuth authentication model you have to do this way.

Comment: in my localhost working fine , but i pur this cod ein my server , my tweets not displaying in my twitter,

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a problem with your code, but more the fact that Twitter is phasing out basic authentication support and moving to OAuth.

There's more information at http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Authentication.

Comment: i looked this oAuth , i thing there no simple example to test oAuth.

Answer (score 0):

This seems very odd, since status updates via the Twitter API are not rate-limited (see [here](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Rate-limiting)), unless you're updating more than [1000 times a day](http://help.twitter.com/forums/10711/entries/15364).

You might work out more of what happened if you uncomment that helpful looking line:

```
//print_r($resultArray);
```

by removing the `//` at the beginning of line.

Answer (score 0):

to tweet using twitter you will need a **post_authenticity_token** along with your ***username*** and ***password***.
this token can be obtained from your profile page by fetching it using curl (after you login with curl). i experimented with curl and was able to tweet using curl. you can find my code at (though it is in bash script, it can be ported to php easily coz they both use *curl*)
http://pastebin.com/a5eBcEeP .

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of PHP libraries that support OAUTH and you can use to write a tweet function in PHP and the 1.1 version of the Twitter API here:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries

[tmhOAuth](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth) is probably my favorite.